# Does the president of any Country require a visa to travel abroad (Official/Leisure)

Tags: visas

I was just wondering is President (of any country) requires a visa for travelling abroad?

Comment: For the UK visa situation, you have to consider monarchs as well as presidents.  Also there are carve outs for those in line to the throne and those related to, or belonging to the royal family.  Obama needs a visa, but enters on diplomatic privilege.  Close voting as too broad. Sorry

Comment: Queen Elizabeth needs no passport to travel anywhere in the world...

Comment: Right. Harry, Wills etc use British passports. Obviously since HM issues them, she can't have one.

Comment: Army officials can travel anywhere in the world without a visa, altough they must arrive in a tank.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the infos. Sorry if the question itself was too broad.

Comment: Why wouldn't? Allowing someone inside a country is a matter of national security. Entry in a country is not a universal right, Just imagine countries with not so good relations, why would one country allow others to other freely?

Comment: For the US, the answer is yes, and it's even explained in details on [state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/diplomat-foreign-government-official.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that yes, they do sometimes need a visa. The details obviously vary, but there is no general exemption or tradition that would allow heads of state to go everywhere in the world without visa or authorisation.

Case in point: The US A-1 visa as explained on [travel.state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/diplomat-foreign-government-official.html). Amusingly, government officials cannot travel on official business under the Visa Waiver Program, even if they come from a country whose citizens do not need a visa to enter the US for other purposes. Heads of state or government (but not other officials) also automatically qualify for this A-1 visa, no matter the purpose of their trip.

In fact, there is [at least one president](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_al-Bashir) who is wanted by international courts and basically cannot leave his country except to a handful of friendly countries or under the cover of the diplomatic immunity conferred to heads of state on official business…